# Break Statement isn't working properly in C Programming Language

Tags: c, break

I am trying to make a simple stopwatch but the break statement isn't working properly. When I made it the first time it worked fine but when I tried to make that again the break statement wasn't working. It's running forever.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")
#define CYCLE 60
int main()
{
int hour, minute, second;
printf("Enter the value of hour, minute and second: ");
scanf("%d%d%d", &hour, &minute, &second);
int h, m, s;
h = 0;
m = 0;
s = 0;
while(1){
    printf("\t\t\t###### Stop Watch ######\n\n\n");
    printf("\t\t\t        %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", h, m, s);
    printf("\t\t\t###### Stop Watch ######\n\n\n");
    if (h == hour && m == minute && s == second){
        break;
    }else{
        clrscr();
    }
    s++;
    sleep(1);
    if (s == CYCLE){
        m++;
        s = 0;
    }
    if (m == CYCLE){
        h++;
        m = 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using scanf incorrectly is a much more likely reason for any problem than a break statement failing. Please show a [mre] without scanf or other vulnerabilities which demonstrates the problem. E.g. use hard coded init values for whatever you are currently reading from input.

Comment: In addition to @Yunnosch s advice, I'd suggest to also output the values of `hour`, `minute` and `second` for debugging reasons or use a debugger to step through your example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to show us what input you provide and what output you got. Also what does "not working correctly" mean? Does it run forever? Does is break just a bit too late? Please edit your question to add missing details.

Comment: `sleep` functions cannot be used for measuring time. They are used for having a process/thread sleep for _at least_ the amount of time specified. Not the _exact_ time specified.

Comment: Generally you should **always** check return  value of `scanf`.

Comment: Did you read some C draft standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ? Did you look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) ? Did you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`? Did you use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program ?

Comment: @Gerhardh Generally, you shouldn't use `scanf()` to begin with...  ;-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't think it it helpful to recommend to a beginner programmer to read the ISO C standard in order to learn C.

Comment: OP could read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score -1):

A 'stopwatch' without any time related function?
Well, all roads lead to rome.

Change your condition

```
(h == hour && m == minute && s == second)
```

to

```
(current_time >= stop_time)
```

where `current_time` is a counter which is continually increased by 1 and `stop_time` the time specified by the user in seconds.

But, it would be best to use functions like:

*<time.h>*

- time
- asctime
- ctime
- localtime
- mktime

*<unistd.h>*

- sleep